# How can I get a PagedList.Pagecount and @Html.PagedListPager to display on same line?

Tags: css, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, pagedlist

In my MVC View, I have a `PagedList.PagedCount` and `@Html.PagedListPager` that successfully display their data, but they appear on separate lines because the `PagedList.PagedCount` is rendered as text without a tag and `@Html.PagedListPager` is rendered as a div block. So it makes sense that there would be a line break. But is there any way to get them on the same line?

So far, I have tried without success:

(1)  Wrapping it with a `<div style="display:inline-block">` wrapper as well as
   `<div style="display:inline">` and it had no effect.

(2) Taking out any spaces between both sets of code. (It makes sense now, but I tried anyway.)

This is the code that shows the Page count and page buttons.

```
Page @(pagedList.PageCount < pagedList.PageNumber ? 
     0 : pagedList.PageNumber) of @pagedList.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(pagedList, page => Url.Action("Index",
new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

This is what it looks like in the browser. [image: How the page count and page list appear in the browser]

This is what the browser source looks like: 
[image: Browser source]

I could try digging into the PagedListPager css class, but at first I wanted to see if anyone knew of a way to place both items on the same line without breaking open the css class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might be a bit of a hack, but can you try your inline styles with an `!important` attribute ?

`<div style="display:inline-block !important">`

Failing that, you could wrap the page count in a div, and add `float:left` to both that and the `pagination-container` class.

**Edit after comments**

I've used the following in an example project and the div's now appear side-by-side. I've created two new div elements and added `vertical-align:middle` and `display:inline-block` to them both.

The Razor view :

```
<div class="page-count" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;">
    Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ?
         0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
</div>

<div class="pagination" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;">
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
</div>
```

The rendered HTML :

```
<div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;" class="page-count">
    Page 5 of 100
</div>

<div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;" class="pagination">
    <div class="pagination-container"><ul class="pagination"><li><a href="/?page=1">1</a></li><li><a href="/?page=2">2</a></li><li><a href="/?page=3">3</a></li><li><a href="/?page=4">4</a></li><li class="active"><a>5</a></li><li><a href="/?page=6">6</a></li><li><a href="/?page=7">7</a></li><li><a href="/?page=8">8</a></li><li><a href="/?page=9">9</a></li><li><a href="/?page=10">10</a></li><li class="disabled PagedList-ellipses"><a>…</a></li><li class="PagedList-skipToNext"><a rel="next" href="/?page=6">»</a></li><li class="PagedList-skipToLast"><a href="/?page=100">»»</a></li></ul></div>
</div>
```

It's not the cleanest solution using inline styles obviously.

Comment: Good ideas. I tried that and some other ideas that inspired. The closest I could get (using the float:left idea) got me without a line break but the page button group placed below the pagecount line.

Comment: When you did that, did you try adding a `vertical-align:middle` to both the page count div and the `pagination-container` class ? I'm not sure if that would help though. Without seeing the CSS for `pagination-container` it is difficult to replicate.

Comment: I looked in the PagedList.css that comes with the NuGet install of PagedList.MVC and cannot find a `pagination-container` or even `container` in the css file. I also tried the vertical-align the first time without any success.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the NuGet package. I've created a test application and amended my answer. Does that solve it ?

Comment: This did the trick. I tried moving the inline styles to a class in my less style, but that method was ineffective. It looks like inline style is the way to go.